# How to populate a list in java with values from other lists of different data types?

Tags: java, list

I have two lists of type `List<A>` and `List<B>`. Now, what I'm trying to do is to create a `List<C>`, the values of which would be read from other two lists. I tried and implemented something like this.

```
public void fileUpload(int customerId) throws SQLException, IOException {
    myList = myTiedosto.getFileDetails(customerId);
    attachmentDetails = myAttachment.getAttachmentDetails(customerId);
    List<Upload> uploadList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Attachment attachment : attachmentDetails) {
        Upload upload = new Upload();
        upload.setUuid(attachment.getUuid());
        for (Tiedosto tiedosto : myList) {
            upload.setCustomerId(tiedosto.getCustomerId());
            upload.setFileName(tiedosto.getFileName());
            upload.setFileSize(tiedosto.getFileSize());
            upload.setContent(tiedosto.getContent());
        }
        uploadList.add(upload);
    }
    for (Upload myUploadList : uploadList) {
        System.out.println(myUploadList.getCustomerId()+" " +myUploadList.getFileName()+" "+myUploadList.getUuid()+" "+myUploadList.getFileSize());
    }
}
```

When I run this, myUploadList returns the same entry twice.
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWevZ.png)

I'm a newbie in Java, I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: Move `uploadList.add(upload);` in inner for loop

Comment: It's not clear what's the relation between the two input lists. Do you want to create an `Upload` instance for each pair of `Attachment` and `Tiedosto`? That's not what you are currently doing, but it's not clear what's the desired output.

Comment: Not surprising, considering you're overwriting most of the fields with those of the last element in `myList`. It's not very clear what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @HemantPatel If I move uploadList.add(upload); in inner for loop, it prints the same entry 4 times.

Comment: all of your upload objects will end up with the info from the last record of your myList because for each upload object you keep setting again and again the fields that you take from myList.

Comment: The 2nd for loop doesn't make sense. What are u trying to do there?

Comment: @isaace I want to populate List<Upload> from the values of myList and attachmentDetails.

Comment: @Eran 's answer looks right for you. Create the Upload Object and add it all in the inner loop.

Comment: your uploadList size should be the size of the attachmentDetails times the size of myList

Comment: @isaace isn't it so that whe I declare a new ArrayList<>(); it should create a dynamic sized array List?

Comment: that's true but your logic is creating a new object for each myList in each attachmentDetails

Comment: how do you know which attachment pairs up with which Tiedosto ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comments, I think this is what you want.

```
int i = 0; 
for (Attachment attachment : attachmentDetails) {
    Upload upload = new Upload();
    upload.setUuid(attachment.getUuid());
    upload.setCustomerId(myList.get(i).getCustomerId());
    upload.setFileName(myList.get(i).getFileName());
    upload.setFileSize(myList.get(i).getFileSize());
    upload.setContent(myList.get(i).getContent());

    uploadList.add(upload);
    i++;
}
```

or if you have a way of identifying which if the myList belongs to which attachment then you can loop through the myList and do a check:

```
  for (Attachment attachment : attachmentDetails) {
    Upload upload = new Upload();
    upload.setUuid(attachment.getUuid());
    for (Tiedosto tiedosto : myList) {
        if(tiedosto.getCustomerId() == attachment.getId()//assuming you have this field
            upload.setCustomerId(tiedosto.getCustomerId());
            upload.setFileName(tiedosto.getFileName());
            upload.setFileSize(tiedosto.getFileSize());
            upload.setContent(tiedosto.getContent());
    }
    uploadList.add(upload);
}
```

Comment: Duuuuuuuuuude, Thank you so much! I can't believe I forgot to use a counter!! You saved my day!! You my hero!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, you should create and add the `Upload` instance to the output `List` inside the inner loop:

```
for (Attachment attachment : attachmentDetails) {
    for (Tiedosto tiedosto : myList) {
        Upload upload = new Upload();
        upload.setUuid(attachment.getUuid());
        upload.setCustomerId(tiedosto.getCustomerId());
        upload.setFileName(tiedosto.getFileName());
        upload.setFileSize(tiedosto.getFileSize());
        upload.setContent(tiedosto.getContent());
        uploadList.add(upload);
    }  
}
```

This will create an `Upload` instance from each pair of `Attachment` and `Tiedosto`.

EDIT:

Based on your latest comment, it would be better to use traditional for loop, since you want to create an `Upload` instance from each pair of `Attachment` and `Tiedosto` instances having the same index:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < attachmentDetails.size(); i++) {
    Tiedosto tiedosto = myList.get(i);
    Upload upload = new Upload();
    upload.setUuid(attachmentDetails.get(i).getUuid());
    upload.setCustomerId(tiedosto.getCustomerId());
    upload.setFileName(tiedosto.getFileName());
    upload.setFileSize(tiedosto.getFileSize());
    upload.setContent(tiedosto.getContent());
    uploadList.add(upload); 
}
```

Comment: it kinda did the job, but now it's returning 4 elements, instead of two. It should return two elements, but it's making a copy of each

Comment: @RoshanUpreti But you said "That's exactly what I'm trying to do. Create an upload instance from each pair of Attachment and Tiedosto." If there are 2 Attachment instances and 2 Tiedosto instances, there should be 4 Upload instances.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. There are 2 Attachments and 2 Tiedosto instances, and they are supposed to produce 2 Upload instances, using the values from attachments and tiedosto, not 4. Really sorry again for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

The entries are not same as both have different UUID. The other details such as CustomerId,Filename, Filesize etc. are same as you are iterating the same myList for each iteration row of the list myAttachment. So, verify whether you are iterating correct with respect to the expected data

Answer (score 0):

Man, It's a logical problem in your program.

I guess it's caused by the inner cycle.

It's overwriting the upload with the last element myList's information. Maybe that's why you have exactly the same information in all the fields, except for the uuid.